# Remove duplicate name output from ESPN NBA Box Score

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

All I'm trying to do is convert the box score from an NBA game into a pandas dataframe. Unfortunately, my output is a bit odd from a player names stand point. I am using the following code...

```
import pandas as pd

box_score = pd.read_html('https://www.espn.com/nba/boxscore/_/gameId/401307851')

score = box_score[0]
away = box_score[1]
home = box_score[2]

score.columns = ['Team', '1', '2', '3', '4', 'T']

box_final = pd.concat([away, home])

box_final.columns = ['Player', 'MIN', 'FG', '3PT', 'FT', 'OREB', 'DREB', 'REB', 'AST', 'STL', 'BLK', 'TO', 'PF', '+/-', 'PTS']

#box_final = box_final[box_final['MIN'] != "Has not entered game"]
box_final = box_final[box_final['MIN'] != "DNP-COACH'S DECISION"]
box_final = box_final[box_final['Player'].notna()]

box_final['FG Made'] = box_final['FG'].str.split('-').str[0]
box_final['FG Att'] = box_final['FG'].str.split('-').str[1]
box_final['3PT Made'] = box_final['3PT'].str.split('-').str[0]
box_final['3PT Att'] = box_final['3PT'].str.split('-').str[1]
box_final['FT Made'] = box_final['FT'].str.split('-').str[0]
box_final['FT Att'] = box_final['FT'].str.split('-').str[1]

print(box_final)
```

...to get the following output.

```
                          Player  MIN      FG  ... 3PT Att FT Made FT Att
0     R. HachimuraR. HachimuraPF   30    5-11  ...       2       0      0
1                  A. LenA. LenC   24     2-6  ...       0       2      2
2     R. WestbrookR. WestbrookPG   40   12-28  ...       9       6      8
3               R. NetoR. NetoPG   29    5-10  ...       2       4      4
4          G. MathewsG. MathewsG   18     1-4  ...       4       0      0
5      C. HutchisonC. HutchisonF   16     2-5  ...       1       4      5
6         D. BertansD. BertansSF   31    5-12  ...      10       0      0
7              R. LopezR. LopezC    7     2-5  ...       0       0      0
8          D. GaffordD. GaffordC   17    8-11  ...       0       0      0
9             I. SmithI. SmithPG   28     3-9  ...       1       0      0
13                          TEAM  NaN  45-101  ...      29      16     19
0         J. CollinsJ. CollinsPF   34    5-12  ...       5       6      8
1            C. CapelaC. CapelaC   28     7-7  ...       0       3      5
2             T. YoungT. YoungPG   37   12-25  ...       8       7      7
3   B. BogdanovicB. BogdanovicSG   40    8-15  ...      10       0      0
4         K. HuerterK. HuerterSG   21     2-6  ...       5       1      2
5     D. GallinariD. GallinariPF   23     2-5  ...       2       0      0
6         O. OkongwuO. OkongwuPF   11     5-7  ...       0       1      2
7               S. HillS. HillSF    9     0-2  ...       2       2      2
8             T. SnellT. SnellSF   23     2-2  ...       1       0      0
9       L. WilliamsL. WilliamsSG   13     1-5  ...       0       2      2
15                          TEAM  NaN   44-86  ...      33      22     28

[22 rows x 21 columns]
```

Any suggestions to prevent the name from repeating? Any assistance is truly appreciated.

Comment: The html page itself repeats the name twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can remove the first name using regex like this,

```py
box_final.Player.apply(lambda x: re.sub("[\s].*[\s]", "", x))

0      R.HachimuraPF
1             A.LenC
2      R.WestbrookPG
3           R.NetoPG
4         G.MathewsG
5       C.HutchisonF
6        D.BertansSF
7           R.LopezC
8         D.GaffordC
9          I.SmithPG
10              TEAM
11       J.CollinsPF
12         C.CapelaC
13         T.YoungPG
14    B.BogdanovicSG
15       K.HuerterSG
16     D.GallinariPF
17       O.OkongwuPF
18          S.HillSF
19         T.SnellSF
20      L.WilliamsSG
21              TEAM
Name: Player, dtype: object
```

Hope this works for you.

**Separating Position**

**You can either split in 1 column,**

```py
a = box_final.Player.apply(lambda x: re.sub('(\\s{2,})', '',' '.join(re.split('([A-Z]{0,2})([A-Z]{0,1}$)',re.sub("[\s].*[\s]", "", x)))))
a = a.iloc[np.where(a != ('T EA M'))]
a

0      R.Hachimura PF
1             A.Len C
2      R.Westbrook PG
3           R.Neto PG
4         G.Mathews G
5       C.Hutchison F
6        D.Bertans SF
7           R.Lopez C
8         D.Gafford C
9          I.Smith PG
11       J.Collins PF
12         C.Capela C
13         T.Young PG
14    B.Bogdanovic SG
15       K.Huerter SG
16     D.Gallinari PF
17       O.Okongwu PF
18          S.Hill SF
19         T.Snell SF
20      L.Williams SG
Name: Player, dtype: object
```

**Or Create a new `Position` Column,**

```py
pd.DataFrame(list(a.str.split(' ')), columns=['Player', 'Position'])
    Player  Position
0   R.Hachimura PF
1   A.Len   C
2   R.Westbrook PG
3   R.Neto  PG
4   G.Mathews   G
5   C.Hutchison F
6   D.Bertans   SF
7   R.Lopez C
8   D.Gafford   C
9   I.Smith PG
10  J.Collins   PF
11  C.Capela    C
12  T.Young PG
13  B.Bogdanovic    SG
14  K.Huerter   SG
15  D.Gallinari PF
16  O.Okongwu   PF
17  S.Hill  SF
18  T.Snell SF
19  L.Williams  SG
```

I think 2nd is what you are looking for.

Comment: That solves it! Thanks for all your help. As extra credit, is there a way to separate the positions (PF, C, SF, PG, SG) from the player column?

Answer (score 0):

Roach's solution is great, and I always like using pandas to parse tables as it uses minimal code. so keep that as the accepted solution, but wanted to offer the alternative of using the espn api.

This will return the data in json format. Pandas also allows you to convert json to a table/dataframe. But with apis, it will be more robust in that a) the structure will likely not change (where as the html may change). And you'll get all the raw data and most likely need to do minimal data/string manipulation.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://secure.espn.com/core/nba/boxscore/_/gameId/401307851'
payload = {'xhr':1}

jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()

boxScoreData = jsonData['gamepackageJSON']['boxscore']['players']

rows = []
for each in boxScoreData:
    statistics = each['statistics'][0]
    for athlete in statistics['athletes']:
        data = pd.json_normalize(athlete).drop('stats', axis=1).to_dict('records')
        if len(athlete['stats']) > 0:
            stats = pd.DataFrame([athlete['stats']], columns=statistics['names']).to_dict('records')
        else:
            stats = [{}]
        
        data[0].update(stats[0])
        rows += data

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

**Output:** *Just showing 1st 5 rows.

```
print(df.head(5).to_string())
             reason  starter  ejected  didNotPlay  active          athlete.uid athlete.displayName athlete.headshot.alt                                           athlete.headshot.href athlete.jersey                      athlete.guid                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             athlete.links athlete.id athlete.position.displayName athlete.position.name athlete.position.abbreviation athlete.shortName MIN     FG  3PT   FT OREB DREB REB AST STL BLK TO PF +/- PTS
0  COACH'S DECISION     True    False       False   False  s:40~l:46~a:4066648       Rui Hachimura        Rui Hachimura  https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nba/players/full/4066648.png              8  40c1bcf6675bf217f97c1d628073f927                          [{'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nba/player/_/id/4066648/rui-hachimura', 'text': 'Player Card'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/stats/_/id/4066648/rui-hachimura', 'text': 'Stats'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/splits/_/id/4066648/rui-hachimura', 'text': 'Splits'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/gamelog/_/id/4066648/rui-hachimura', 'text': 'Game Log'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/news/_/id/4066648/rui-hachimura', 'text': 'News'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/bio/_/id/4066648/rui-hachimura', 'text': 'Bio'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/_/id/4066648/rui-hachimura', 'text': 'Overview'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/advancedstats/_/id/4066648/rui-hachimura', 'text': 'Advanced Stats'}]    4066648                Power Forward         Power Forward                            PF      R. Hachimura  30   5-11  1-2  0-0    2    4   6   3   0   0  0  2  -2  11
1  COACH'S DECISION     True    False       False    True  s:40~l:46~a:2596107            Alex Len             Alex Len  https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nba/players/full/2596107.png             27  56df8855ab0a659aeed2ccb77a2b77f7                                                                  [{'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nba/player/_/id/2596107/alex-len', 'text': 'Player Card'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/stats/_/id/2596107/alex-len', 'text': 'Stats'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/splits/_/id/2596107/alex-len', 'text': 'Splits'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/gamelog/_/id/2596107/alex-len', 'text': 'Game Log'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/news/_/id/2596107/alex-len', 'text': 'News'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/bio/_/id/2596107/alex-len', 'text': 'Bio'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/_/id/2596107/alex-len', 'text': 'Overview'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/advancedstats/_/id/2596107/alex-len', 'text': 'Advanced Stats'}]    2596107                       Center                Center                             C            A. Len  24    2-6  0-0  2-2    3    7  10   2   2   1  0  2  +0   6
2  COACH'S DECISION     True    False       False    True     s:40~l:46~a:3468   Russell Westbrook    Russell Westbrook     https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nba/players/full/3468.png              4  e849e50fb1b742561de2ca49862e218d                  [{'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nba/player/_/id/3468/russell-westbrook', 'text': 'Player Card'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/stats/_/id/3468/russell-westbrook', 'text': 'Stats'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/splits/_/id/3468/russell-westbrook', 'text': 'Splits'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/gamelog/_/id/3468/russell-westbrook', 'text': 'Game Log'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/news/_/id/3468/russell-westbrook', 'text': 'News'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/bio/_/id/3468/russell-westbrook', 'text': 'Bio'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/_/id/3468/russell-westbrook', 'text': 'Overview'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/advancedstats/_/id/3468/russell-westbrook', 'text': 'Advanced Stats'}]       3468                  Point Guard           Point Guard                            PG      R. Westbrook  40  12-28  4-9  6-8    1    4   5  15   3   0  4  3  -4  34
3  COACH'S DECISION     True    False       False    True  s:40~l:46~a:2968361           Raul Neto            Raul Neto  https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nba/players/full/2968361.png             19  a8463c665dc5f3c3f84682a998120b9f                                                          [{'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nba/player/_/id/2968361/raul-neto', 'text': 'Player Card'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/stats/_/id/2968361/raul-neto', 'text': 'Stats'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/splits/_/id/2968361/raul-neto', 'text': 'Splits'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/gamelog/_/id/2968361/raul-neto', 'text': 'Game Log'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/news/_/id/2968361/raul-neto', 'text': 'News'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/bio/_/id/2968361/raul-neto', 'text': 'Bio'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/_/id/2968361/raul-neto', 'text': 'Overview'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/advancedstats/_/id/2968361/raul-neto', 'text': 'Advanced Stats'}]    2968361                  Point Guard           Point Guard                            PG           R. Neto  29   5-10  0-2  4-4    1    2   3   2   0   0  0  5  -3  14
4  COACH'S DECISION     True    False       False   False  s:40~l:46~a:3913180    Garrison Mathews     Garrison Mathews  https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nba/players/full/3913180.png             24  fdeab1798e3a6206a336412ef2916015  [{'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nba/player/_/id/3913180/garrison-mathews', 'text': 'Player Card'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/stats/_/id/3913180/garrison-mathews', 'text': 'Stats'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/splits/_/id/3913180/garrison-mathews', 'text': 'Splits'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/gamelog/_/id/3913180/garrison-mathews', 'text': 'Game Log'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/news/_/id/3913180/garrison-mathews', 'text': 'News'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/bio/_/id/3913180/garrison-mathews', 'text': 'Bio'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/_/id/3913180/garrison-mathews', 'text': 'Overview'}, {'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nba/player/advancedstats/_/id/3913180/garrison-mathews', 'text': 'Advanced Stats'}]    3913180                        Guard                 Guard                             G        G. Mathews  18    1-4  1-4  0-0    0    0   0   0   1   0  0  2  +4   3
```